# How can I load data on page load?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm using the hashchange event to know when the URI has changed and load content into a div, but i would like to get the hashtag on the first load of the page to load the content into the div . . . and if it doesn't have hashtag load a default page into the div

this is my code . . .

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
    $('#content').load('<? echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controller/'+ hash)
});
```

Comment: What is the question? Please be more specific as the question is unclear.

Comment: @alisamii The question is clear for me, he wants to load data on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event on DOM [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) so the handler is executed once when the page is loaded.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {

    var url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controller/';
    if (window.location.hash) url += '...';

    $('#content').load(url);

}).trigger('hashchange');
```

Note that older browsers do not support this event.